# How to create second window that shows part of main window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, desktop-application

I have application with WPF Ribbon and Grid. And I need to show this Grid not only in main application window but also on second window. This Grid contain a lot of elements like ToggleButtons, TextBoxes, Images. 
Scheme of my application code looks like that:

```
<ribbon:RibbonWindow
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        [...]
        xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
        Title="MainWindow"
        x:Name="RibbonWindow"
        Height="870" Width="1000">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ribbon:Ribbon x:Name="Ribbon">
        [...]
        </ribbon:Ribbon>

        <Grid Background="#FF5C5C5C" Height="765" Width="986" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,-2,-70" x:Name="MainGrid">
            <ToggleButton/>
            <TextBlock />
            <ToggleButton/>
            <Rectangle />
            [...]
         </Grid>

    </Grid>
</ribbon:RibbonWindow>
```

`MainGrid` is the Grid that I want to show in second window. It can even be only view of this Grid. But when I change something in first window, like write something in TextBox or click on ToggleButton, I need to have it visible on second screen too.

Comment: Updated my answer, added a demo and some code, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm this is going to be tricky. What I would do is create a UserControl with the Grid and then put one UserControl in Window1 and another in Window2. But to synchronize the state of the Window1-Grid and the Window2-Grid you will have to bind them to the same object.

**Edit: Here, cooked up an example for you**

**Step 1:** Put the `Grid` into a `UserControl` so it can be reused.

Notice I set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property on the binding to `PropertyChanged`, this updates the source object as the user is typing, so we will see changes in `Window2` as they are happening in `Window1`.

**CommonGrid.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WindowSync.CommonGrid"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"  />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
            <TextBlock Text="Name: " />
            <TextBox Width="200" Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsAdmin, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <TextBlock Text=" Is Admin" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Step 2:** Put the `UserControl` into the desired windows.

Note: you have to reference the namespace that `UserControl` is in, in this case the namespace is `WindowSync`, this line lets us user the namespace `xmlns:app="clr-namespace:WindowSync"`.

**Window1.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WindowSync.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:app="clr-namespace:WindowSync"
        Title="Window 1" Height="200" Width="400">
    <app:CommonGrid x:Name="Window1Grid" />
</Window>
```

**Windo1.xaml.cs**

```
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Window1Grid.DataContext = Person.User; // bind the UserControl in Window1 to the an object
        new Window2().Show(); // create an instance of window 2 and show it
    }
```

**Window2.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WindowSync.Window2"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:app="clr-namespace:WindowSync"
        Title="Window 2" Height="200" Width="400">
    <app:CommonGrid x:Name="Window2Grid" />
</Window>
```

**Window2.xaml.cs**

```
    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Window2Grid.DataContext = Person.User; // bind the UserControl in Window2 to the same object
    }
```

**Person.cs**

I just created a random object called person for the demonstration.

Note: you have to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your object, and raise the appropriate `PropertyChanged` event whenever something is changed, this is what let's us synchronize the two grids. Window1 changes something, the `PropertyChanged` event gets fired, `Window2` picks it up and makes the changes.

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static Person User = new Person();

    #region Name
    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region IsAdmin
    private bool _IsAdmin;
    public bool IsAdmin
    {
        get { return _IsAdmin; }
        set
        {
            _IsAdmin = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsAdmin");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Anywyas, I hope this helps you out. I uploaded a zipped version of the project if you get stuck. http://www.mediafire.com/?yv84xbben6tjdy7

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this code! It is working very well for 'check' action. But I have problem with binding IsEnabled property. I have added binding to control like that: <ToggleButton x:Name="A11" Content="11" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabledA11, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Click="OnSeatButtonClick" /> but it is not working. When I run application ToggleButton is disabled, and when I change its state (using function), the current state is not transferred to second window.

Comment: Hey, are you raising the PropertyChanged event for the property? Post your full code here, and I will try to help you out. I'm heading out for now and will be back late in the night, I'll look at it then.

Comment: I have added Mode=TwoWay and now it is working just great. Thank you very much for your help!